# 666 permission even after making umask= 0000

Tags: unix, permissions, aix, umask

I made my umask = 0000. However when I am creating a file it has 666 permission. Although directories get 777 , that's alright.

Also my aim is to create file/dir with permissions 774, I guess umask for this will be 003?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Umask does not provide executable rights on files. So this is correct.

`umask 0003` will create directories with permissions that equals 774.
But for files you will have to set the executable premissions on your own. Umask does not serve that feature.

`chmod 774 file`